# How to filter the html markups when render a template with jinja2?

Tags: django, templates, jinja2

Now I'm biulding a django project with jinja2 dealing with templates. Some page contents are submited by the client with wysiwy editor, and thing's going fine with the detail pages.

But the list pages are wrong with the slice of the contents.

My code:

```
<div class="summary ">
     <div class="content">{{ question.content[:200]|e}}...</div> 
</div>
```

But the output is:

```
<p>what i want to show here &nbsp;is raw text without markups</p>...
```

The expected result is that the html markups like `<p></p> <section>....` are gone (filtered or eliminated) and only the raw text shows!

So how can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [striptags](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#striptags) filter:

> **striptags(value)**
>
> Strip SGML/XML tags and replace adjacent whitespace
>   by one space.

```
<div class="content">{{ question.content|striptags}}...</div>
```

Jinja2 `striptags` [filter test](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/blob/master/jinja2/testsuite/filters.py#L71) will also help you to understand how it works.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you very fine with {{ question.content|striptags|truncate(250, True)}}